# How do I restore the pickle after import pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, pickle

Python 3.7  pyspark 2.4

```
import pickle
from collections import namedtuple
B = namedtuple('B', [])
pickle.dumps(B())
# b'\x80\x03c__main__\nB\nq\x00)\x81q\x01.'

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

pickle.dumps(B())
# b'\x80\x03cpyspark.serializers\n_restore\nq\x00X\x01\x00\x00\x00Bq\x01))\x87q\x02Rq\x03.'
```

importing pyspark seems to have side effect of messing with pickle. As a result, people need to have pyspark installed when unpickling. How do I use the original `pickle` to serialize the data that is spark irrelevant?

Update: It doesn't help if I import pickle after spark

```
from collections import namedtuple
B = namedtuple('B', [])

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pickle
pickle.dumps(B())
# b'\x80\x03cpyspark.serializers\n_restore\nq\x00X\x01\x00\x00\x00Bq\x01))\x87q\x02Rq\x03.'
```

Comment: Does the difference still show up if you import pickle after pyspark?

Comment: @Hoog It doesn't help

Comment: Can you describe your use case more, what do you need pickle for. Unfortunately there isn't a universal, simple fix for this but there might be a fix that's good enough for your use case.